# Installation of explore package in Groovy (ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: ros, explore, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have been trying to install the ROS explore package: http://www.ros.org/wiki/explore Unfortunately, there are no binaries available in the form of

> apt-get install ros-groovy-*

Therefore, I downloaded it from the svn repository and tried to compile it with rosmake, but I have received the following error:

> /opt/ros/rosws/exploration/explore/include/explore/explore_frontier.h:45:34:
> fatal error: LinearMath/btVector3.h:
> No such file or directory compilation
> terminated.

I googled the error, and tried to install several packpages like libbullet-dev liblinear-dev but the problem is still there, thus any help is appreciated. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57084/installation-of-explore-package-in-groovy-(ubuntu-12.10)/) by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 483 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lewis longman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9601/lewis-longman/) on 2013-12-06**:
hello, have you solved the problem? I meet the same problem with you, if you get it through, please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I looked into the explore package a few months ago, it wasn't compatible with Groovy, and looked like it was unmaintained. In particular, I think the navigation or costmap API has changed, and explore hasn't been updated to match.

I remember it working in Electric, and I don't think I tried it on Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-03-05**:
Thank you, that leads me to another [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/57090/is-there-any-ros-package-for-exploration-in-groovy-ubuntu-1210/)

**Comment by [nikkihohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4243/nikkihohn/) on 2013-03-23**:
Do you know if the explore package has been updated to be compatible with Groovy now?